# How long will Blue Origin's New Shepard space tourist flights last?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, blue-origin, tourism, new-shepard

I tried searching for this, but everything I found says the New Shepard flights will last only a few minutes.

Does Blue Origin have stated (or show evidence of likely future) plans for the commercial passenger flights in the future be significantly longer than that? Or will passengers really paying thousands of dollars to be in space and/or free-fall for 5 minutes or so?

Comment: The words "suborbital spaceflight" as the first words on Blue Origin's webpage for the [New Shepard](https://www.blueorigin.com/new-shepard/) mean that, yes, the flights will last a few minutes.  The [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Shepard#Mission) suggests the total flight will be 10 minutes, but only says so for the first stage, rather than the crew capsule itself.

Comment: I think your question boils down to "How long are passengers on New Shepard in space?" To which there's a couple questions around what "space" means but that might get you better answers

Comment: it's a good question; I've adjusted the wording a bit to fit the site and to be sure to ask only for fact-based answers.

Comment: @Ghedipunk I've just asked [How many hours long is Earth's longest possible sub-orbital flight?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/40432/12102)

Comment: They will be as long as the existing flight - otherwise the manikin testing they've done would have been pointless.

Comment: @stickyz That’s just not true. The question is very clear as stated: how long from liftoff to touchdown? That’s the duration of the flight, and it does not boil down to how long you’re in space, which as you noted is subjective—plus, the descent phase through the atmosphere could easily be a sizable chunk of the whole flight. Please don’t be rash editing questions because it could simply be you misinterpreting the question. It seems as a rule you should edit only if there really clearly truly is a super critical mistake. Otherwise, please let the words of the OP not be obfuscated by yours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it will only be a few minutes. (Source: blueorigin.com)

[image]